# Install Eclipse Classic 4.2.1 in ubuntu 10,04

Tags: installation, eclipse

I download Eclipse Classic 4.2.1 from http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/ and it is not .deb, it is .tar.gz. how can i install this package??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need not install. just right click and extract it.you will find a file called eclipse which is an executable.Just run that.Some times you need to give the execute permissions to the file. that can be done in permissions tab of its properties(right-click properties) window.

Answer (score 2):

Eclipse doesn't really need 'installation' if you download it from the Eclipse website. You can simply extract it from the terminal like so:

```
tar -xzf elipse.tar.gz
```

Once extracted, your home directory is a good place to put the eclipse program folder.

Alternatively, you can choose to have the package manager install Eclipse by running:

```
sudo apt-get install eclipse
```

Although, that will effectively require you do download it again.

Comment: `sudo ln -snf /usr/bin/eclipse /DIR/eclipse/bin/eclipse` after unpacking the tar.gz file, that would be perfect.